# get request to me/inbox misses first message of the conversation

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am using Graph API of facebook to read user's messages.

https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?method=GET&path=me%2Finbox

To get the access token, I have selected 'read_mailbox' permission.

On submitting the request, I get the response as JSON string, but the response does not contain first message of the conversation.

What am I missing?

Thanks and Regards,

Arjabh

Answer (score 1):

You missed nothing. The Facebook Graph API returns a thread with all messages. You will need read the parameter "unread" and after parse the JSON content, get the last X ("unread") messages of the thread. They are the unread messages.